# problems with project (coredata+rss)

Tags: uitableview, core-data, rss

i have an source code from github:

> https://github.com/c3522541/RSSFun

It's a simple rss-reader. I want to understand how to save the list of news using coredata.
I started with creating of data model and `NSMenegedObjectSubclass`, that was done!

But what should I do the next?
I have no ideas, I tried to make something like that:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723

in project, but it does not work.

please help me with some advice

Comment: Try following this tutorial, it is very helpfull and has a lot of screenshots: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started